# CMOS AC-to-DC Converter Design

Tags: circuits, rf-electronics, circuit-design, microelectronics, cmos

I am trying to analytically model the power conversion efficiency of an AC-to-DC power converter circuit (see Figure 1). In this design, the drain-source voltage of each MOS device can be expressed as having both a DC and large signal AC part:

$$ V_{RF}(t) = V_{DC} + V_{AC}(t) $$

[image]

As the AC input signal magnitude for this design is large ($\approx V_{TH}$, the device threshold voltage), I cannot create a small-signal model for this device. I am looking to develop a model for both the device conduction losses and parasisitic capacitance losses in steady-state operation. The parasitic capacitances that I would like to include are $C_{dg}, C_{gs}$ and $C_{oss}$ (Figure 2).

[image]

I would appreciate any information (videos, textbooks, equations etc) detailing how I can approach this design.

Thank You.

Comment: not that there aren't smart folks here who can answer, but would be better placed in the electronics SE, which is really Electrical Engineering, they eat stuff like this up.